# Swift JSONSerialization.jsonObject Error

Tags: json, swift, error-handling, nsmutablearray, jsonserializer

I've looked around but I don't find an answer to fix this error that has been bugging me. I tried adding a "as! NSMutableArray" but that gave me another error. Any ideas on how to fix it? I converted my project from Objective-C to Swift, so hopefully the code is all good I had 20+ errors now I'm down to 3 errors. Thank you.

**Error Message:**

```
'jsonObject' produces 'Any', not the expected contextual result type 'NSMutableArray'
```

[image: code error picture]

**Code for retrieving data from server**

```
// Retrieving Data from Server
func retrieveData() {

    let getDataURL = "http://ip/example.org/json.php"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: getDataURL)!

    do {

        let data: NSData = try NSData(contentsOf: url as URL)
        jsonArray = JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: nil)
    }
    catch {
        print("Error: (data: contentsOf: url)")
    }

    // Setting up dataArray
    var dataArray: NSMutableArray = []

    // Looping through jsonArray
    for i in 0..<jsonArray.count {

        // Create Data Object

        let dID: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "id") as! String
        let dName: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "dataName") as! String
        let dStatus1: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "dataStatus1") as! String
        let dStatus2: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "dataStatus2") as! String
        let dURL: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "dataURL") as! String

        // Add Data Objects to Data Array
        dataArray.add(Data(dataName: dName, andDataStatus1: dStatus1, andDataStatus2: dStatus2, andDataURL: dURL, andDataID: dID))
    }

    self.myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `jsonObject` function will return a value of type `Any` but the `jsonArray`'s type of `NSMutableArray`. And this function will throw an error if something is wrong, put a `try` keyword before it. In my experience, let change the type of `jsonArray` to array of dictionary, so you will extract data with ease.

```
    do {
        let data: Data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
        let jsonArray: [[String: AnyObject]] = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [[String: AnyObject]]
        print("json: \(jsonArray)")

        for dict in jsonArray {
            let dataName = dict["dataName"] as! String
            print("dataName: \(dataName)")
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Error: (data: contentsOf: url)")
    }
```

Comment: Okay so I tried the code and I got 2 errors, one saying "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Data' with an argument list of type '(contentsOf: URL)' " and the second error saying "Ambiguous reference to member 'jsonObject(with:options:)' " - No idea what they mean

Comment: Did you use Swift 2 or 3?

Comment: I used Swift 3.

Comment: I see you have own type named `Data`, let use other name. In Swift 3, Apple removed prefix `NS`, so `NSData` became `Data`.

Comment: Let rename this type `Data(dataName: dName, andDataStatus1: dStatus1, andDataStatus2: dStatus2, andDataURL: dURL, andDataID: dID)`

Comment: Okay so anything with the word "Data" I rename even in my NSObject class since it gets it from there?

Comment: Okay awesome everything worked but just to understand the code you gave me, you have this line in it "let dataName = dict["dataName"] as! String" is this replacing the objects that I made below?

Comment: Also, since I renamed everything to "game" do I change anything in your code? For example this code " let data: Data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL) "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127511/discussion-between-brosimple-and-danh-huynh).

Comment: I ran into a problem, nothing is showing up in the table view